# Python html missing when scraping website

Tags: python, html, web

I tried to scrape a website using code like

```py
import requests
requests.get("myurl.com").content
```

But some important elements from the website were missing. How can I get the *whole* website content with Python 3, just like I would use the inspector in Firefox or other browsers?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try Scrapy, Selenium or even Splash? They are powerful scraping libraries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Beautiful Soup, a python library for scraping, for this purpose. Simply import it at the top:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then, add these lines to your code

```
data = requests.get("myurl.com").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: This changes nothing

Comment: What elements are missing from your result?

Comment: The html; The only thing except for <html>, <head> (with all the html in the head) and <body> I get, is javascript code

Comment: This is strange, try adding headers like this maybe?

`headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }`
And then,

`data = requests.get("myurl.com", headers).text`